# Объединиение или наследование C++

Tags: c++, память

Всем привет, разрабатываю язык программирования на c++ (надо для учёбы), но в плюсах я пока новичок, и отсюда возникают различные вопросы из раздела "а как лучше?"

Собственно, в чём проблема: нужен менеджер динамической памяти (грубо говоря, это штука, которая какому-то имени присваивает какие-то данные). Тип данных может меняться (это может быть, например, массив из чаров или инстанс какого-то класса — не важно). К текущему моменту я использовал объединения (union), в которых я просто перечислял возможные варианты типов.

```
    union JMemoryDataPointer {
        int* intData;
        float* floatData;
        char* stringData;
        bool* boolData;
    } data;
```

Но недавно подумал, что можно сделать какой-то класс, например, Data и потом наплодить ему детей DataInteger, DataThing и т.д.

Ну, и собственно, вопрос: какой вариант лучше и почему? (хотя бы по вашему мнению)

Comment: А не проще работать с `void*` и просто выполнять приведение типа, когда нужно?..

Comment: Я в таких случаях делаю базовый класс и все наследую от него. Очень удобно. например, если нужно вывести содержимое - просто в цикле прошлись и дернули функцию классаprint. А каждый элемент уже решил, как именно он выводиться. Если использовать класс, в котором просто перечисленны все варианты, то придется добавлять туда новые типы и модифицировать весь класс - хранить переменную, которая определяет тип содержимого, каждая фунция класса знает о всех возможных типах и содержит switch. Метод с void ничем не лучше.

Comment: Обьединение не связано с наследованием вообще. это разные операции. Обьединение используется если разные типы данных нужно хранить в одной переменной в той же самой области памяти (VARIANT - тип например )

Comment: @nick_n_a собственно, думаю, отсюда и возникает мой вопрос. Есть идейно правильный способ решения проблемы — через объединения, и есть способ решения путём наследования, который, возможно, чуть более громоздкий, но как подсказывает здравый смысл, чуть более гибкий,

Comment: **Есть идейно правильный способ решения проблемы** - нет, это не идейно правильный с точки зрения с++.

Comment: @KoVadim да, я пока что тоже склоняюсь к этому варианту, но хочется узнать, кто и что ещё по этому поводу думает. Если я на этом этапе вкосячусь, то придётся много чего переписывать в будущем.

Comment: Задача наследования - разширение функционала (Наследование не всегда даже приводит к большему потреблению памяти, но часто). А задача обьединения - более рациональное использование памяти (или для сокращение расхода памяти, или для удобства использования памяти). эти два понятия нельзя сравнивать, это как мухи и котлеты. Всё равно что спорить что лучше сложение или умножение.

Comment: @KoVadim тогда вопрос: что в нём идейно неправильного?

Comment: есть ещё как минимум пара способов хранить данные - можно сделать свой менеджер памяти, с ручным выделением байт и размещением там данных. Можно поделить переменные по типам и запихнуть в разные списки, а можно на шаблонах все сделать. И Ваш язык будет компилироваться на этапе компиляции:) А можно использовать llvm и пусть это будет его проблема.

Comment: Ну хорошо, теперь вроде всё понятно. Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

У вашего метода есть несколько серьёзных изъянов:

1. **Необходимость нисходящего приведения** от базового класса к дочернему (в [случае *@KoVadim*-а](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/646303/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-c#comment921636_646303)) или небезопасного обращения к полям объединения (в вашем случае). При этом можно легко опечататься и случайно преобразовать не к тому типу с плачевным результатом.
2. **Отсутствие контроля обработки всех возможных типов** в перечислении. Особо остро данная проблема встанет при добавлении поддержки нового элемента перечисления в изрядно разросшуюся программу.
3. **Отсутствие возможности хранения чего-либо, отличного от примитивных типов данных**. Пока это несущественно, но в будущем может возникнуть необходимость инкапсуляции некой логики в тип о *типе данных вашего языка программирования*. Примером такой логики может служить проверка значений параметров при их изменении. Из-за этого поля придётся делать закрытыми, выставляя вместо них методы. Следом за методами появится и конструктор, который нельзя будет вызвать из `union`-а.

**Для решения первой проблемы** был придуман шаблон проектирования «Посетитель» («Visitor»). Его суть заключается в том, что информация о текущем типе хранимого значения известна только контейнеру (`union`) и наружу не передаётся. Как же тогда работать с хранимой переменной, спросите вы. Очень просто. При необходимости доступа к переменной мы передаём контейнеру совокупность обработчиков, каждый из которых предназначен для работы со своим определённым типом. Контейнер же сам выбирает из них нужный и вызывает его с преобразованным в соответствующий тип значением.

Удобной реализацией этого шаблона проектирования является класс [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/variant.html). Для обработки хранимого типа у него имеется функция [`boost::apply_visitor()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost/apply_visitor.html), принимающая экземпляр некоего класса с перегрузками метода `T_out operator()(T_in)`. Да-да, обработчики могут ещё и возвращать значения по результатам работы с переменной. В придачу этот метод может быть ещё и шаблонным, покрывая сразу несколько (или все) типов за раз.

Наконец, этот класс **решает две оставшиеся проблемы** ещё на этапе компиляции.

Рассмотрим его использование на примере:

```
#include <boost/variant/variant.hpp>

// Вспомогательный класс владеющего указателя (урезанный аналог std::unique_ptr из C++11)
template<class T> class MyUniqueArrayPtr
{
    T* _ptr;

public:
    explicit MyUniqueArrayPtr(size_t count) : _ptr(new[] T(count)) {}
    ~MyUniqueArrayPtr() {delete[] _ptr;}

    T* operator*() const {return _ptr};
    T* operator->() const {return _ptr};
};

// Контейнер информации о переменных
typedef variable_t boost::variant<
    MyUniqueArrayPtr<int>,
    MyUniqueArrayPtr<float>,
    MyUniqueArrayPtr<char>,
    MyUniqueArrayPtr<bool>
>;

// Класс для получения строкового представления значения переменной (для редактора кода
// или отладчика)
class StringifyingVisitor : public boost::static_visitor<std::string>
{
public:
    // Шаблонный метод, преобразующий в строку всё, поддерживаемое std::to_string()
    template<class T>
    std::string operator()(T val) const
    {
        // Доступна, начиная с C++11; приведена просто для примера
        return std::to_string(*val);
    }
};

// Класс для компиляции машинного кода
class CompilationVisitor : public boost::static_visitor<>
{
public:
    // Пусть в конструкторе будет передаваться общий тип действия для переменной,
    // чтобы компилятор смог наставить машинной команде нужных типозависимых флагов.
    explicit CompilationVisitor(Command command)
    {
        // ...
    }

    // С boost::variant можно принимать и константные ссылки. А можно и неконстантные.
    void operator()(const MyUniqueArrayPtr<int>& val)
    {
        // ...
    }

    void operator()(const MyUniqueArrayPtr<float>& val)
    {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
};

// Тестовая функция, принимающая откуда-то информацию о переменной
void foo(const variable_t& variable)
{
    // Методы первого посетителя шаблонные, поэтому его можно создать прямо по месту
    // вызова
    std::cout << boost::apply_visitor(StringifyingVisitor(), variable) << std::endl;

    // Второй посетитель
    CompilationVisitor compiler(someCommand);
    boost::apply_visitor(compiler, variable);
}
```

Comment: Весьма интересно.

Не скажу, что до конца понимаю что происходит в приведённом примере, но паттерн я загуглил, и думаю, что вариант с ним стоит того, чтобы его опробовать.

Comment: Не, по итогу так и не смог это никак применить.

Сделал несколько хеш-таблиц под определённые типы данных и объединил их в один класс. Несколько избыточно, но не криминально, да и думаю, что так будет лучше для всех.

Answer (score 0):

Когда-то мне что-то подобное нужно было, а использовать шаблоны было нельзя в итоге сделал такую вот штуковину:
[github](https://github.com/eSkry/TMX-Loader-TME/tree/Loader_V7/Loader)
Смотрите файлы `datatilepropertys.h` и `datatilepropertys.cpp` там есть методы `as_int()`, `as_string()` и т.д.